# How to get all storage account name and their access key of Azure using Python

Tags: python, azure, cloud, azure-storage

i'm not able to read all the azure storage account name and therir key.

```
AZURE_TENANT_ID = '<string>'
AZURE_CLIENT_ID = '<string>'
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET = '<string>'
AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = '<string>'
import os
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.storage.models import (
     StorageAccountCreateParameters,
     StorageAccountUpdateParameters,
     Sku,
     SkuName,
     Kind
    )

subscription_id = AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID # your Azure Subscription Id
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
client_id=AZURE_CLIENT_ID,
secret=AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET,
tenant=AZURE_TENANT_ID
)
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
storage_client = StorageManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
print(resource_client,storage_client)
# Retrieve the list of resource groups
for item in storage_client.storage_accounts.list():
    print_item(item)
```

and after this this code i get this bug

```
AttributeError: 'ServicePrincipalCredentials' object has no attribute 'get_token'
```

and while debugging i found that "storage_client.storage_accounts.list()" this statement return iterator object of azure.core.paging.ItemPaged class and it return the same object all the time

pls help me out

Answer (score 2):

We have created the below python script to pull the list of storage accounts &  their respective access keys under a particular subscription.

In the below code we have used the `ClientSecretCredential` libraries  under `azure.identity` instead of  `ServicePrincipalCredentials` which is a newer libraries to authenticate with token credentials  based on the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate-service-principals#authenticate-with-token-credentials).

**Here is the python Code:**

```
AZURE_TENANT_ID  =  '<tenantid>'
AZURE_CLIENT_ID  =  '<clientid>'
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET  =  '<clientsecret>'
AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID  =  '<subscriptionid>'
    
import  os
from  azure.identity  import  ClientSecretCredential
from  azure.mgmt.resource  import  ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.storage.models import  (StorageAccountCreateParameters,StorageAccountUpdateParameters,
Sku,SkuName,Kind)
    
subscription_id  =  AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID  # your Azure Subscription Id
credentials  =  ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=AZURE_TENANT_ID,client_id=AZURE_CLIENT_ID,client_secret=AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET)
resource_client  =  ResourceManagementClient(credentials,  subscription_id)
storage_client  = StorageManagementClient(credentials,  subscription_id)
    
# Retrieve the list of resource groups
resourcelist=resource_client.resource_groups.list()
for  item  in  resourcelist:
    for  item1  in  resource_client.resources.list_by_resource_group(item.name):
        if(item1.type=='Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts'):
            storage_keys  =  storage_client.storage_accounts.list_keys(item.name,  item1.name)
            storage_keys  =  {v.key_name:  v.value for  v  in  storage_keys.keys}
            print(item.name,('\tKey 1: {}'.format(storage_keys['key1'])))
            print(item.name,('\tKey 2: {}'.format(storage_keys['key2'])))
```

**Here is the Output screenshot for reference :**

[image]

**Note:**

The service principal that you are using for authentication in the above code,needs to have RBAC role `storage Account Contributor` for the whole subscription.